# Gulp issue when copying over fonts

Tags: npm, gulp

Every now and then, when I do a gulp build, I would get this error:

```
Error: EEXIST, mkdir 'Users/username/Desktop/Project/dist/fonts' at Error (native)
```

It doesn't happen on every build though. My gulp code to copy over fonts is:

```
gulp.src(paths.fonts { cwd: bases.app })
.pipe(flatten()) // using gulp-flatten
.pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'fonts/'));
```

Is there a way for me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to delete the old `fonts/` folder first.

Use something like **[Gulp del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del)**:

I also like [gulp-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util) for gulp console logs:

```
gulp.task('removeFonts', function(cb) {
    del([bases.dist + 'fonts/'], cb);
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.magenta('Fonts folder removed');
});
```

Then call your mkdir build.

Comment: I have a clean gulp task that runs during each build and yet I still get this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the folder is deleted first? Can you watch your folders in the finder to see how it updates. You can also see in the sidebar of Sublime text. Also try adding logs.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be deleting all files before it recreates the file.